# Is it possible to add custom metadata to an SQLite column?

Tags: sqlite, metadata

Is it possible to add custom metadata to an SQLite column?  Or will I need to store it in a separate column or table?

I'm working on a database where I'd like to store the units of a column in some form, i.e. a Temperature column being in units of Kelvin.  Is it possible to store this as a string or some form of custom metadata attached to the column?

Comment: What effect should that "metadata" have?

Comment: None while in the database.  It could be for presentation on retrieving the data from the database, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe no. You could add another column. You could also encode the metadata into the value somehow (["fruit:apple", "fruit:pear", "mineral:bauxite", ...]), but that makes a lot of data harder and less efficient to handle.

Generally, you probably want only one type of data in a column anyway.