# Organizing and retrieving custom column metadata in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am making a SQLite database and want to have a way to add descriptions of the columns. For example, I may have table `measurements` with columns `size` and `weight` and want to add metadata on how the values in these columns were measured (eg. "Measured from fingertip to fingertip", "Measured at 10 AM").

How should I organize this extra information? In a separate table `metadata` with columns `table`, `column` and `description`? Wouldn't it be difficult to retrieve? Can I in some way use the descriptions as ALIAS?

EDIT. I am aware that [it is not possible to add metadata directly to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748106/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-metadata-to-an-sqlite-column) so the question is how to store the metadata in a way that makes them easily appendable/accessible when running queries on the corresponding columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add custom metadata to an SQLite column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748106/is-it-possible-to-add-custom-metadata-to-an-sqlite-column)

Comment: Thank you, @MarkBenningfield, for wanting to help, but unfortunately no; adding an entire column for each existing column, with repeted information, seems too inefficient, and the metadata is too long to have as a prefix. So the main question is how the metadata should be stored to still be easily accessible through queries

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that tables and columns are expensive

Comment: *easily appendable/accessible when running queries on the corresponding columns* means a new column for each existing column with the metadata. Not so *easily appendable/accessible when running queries on the corresponding columns* but manageable means a new column for each existing column with references to metadata values stored in another table.

Comment: Have the same need, will most probably create a new tables  where to store for each table & column the metadata as rows (e.g. table: sys_meta_info columns: table_name, column_name, metadata_name, metadata_value)